# Spring security not loading the page giving 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Since I am learning springs security, I was trying my first example below and it is giving me 404 error. Please find the security config file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hello"
            access="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER" />
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER"
                    name="car" password="scarvarez" />
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER"
                    name="mon" password="scarvarez" />
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER"
                    name="bea" password="scarvarez" />
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER"
                    name="andr" password="scarvarez" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Later on I have a servlet as follows

```
package com.security.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/hello" })
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2218168052197231866L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("Hello World");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything here goes fine except when I login, instead of hello world it gives me 404. Nothing is present on the tomcat console as such. Just wanted to know what may the problem be with this?

Edit:-- Please find my `web.xml` file

```
<web-app>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why are you  using `HttpServlet` in Spring?

Comment: It is `/hello` URL which I called. It is the same URL which calls and login and after success, calls Hello World

Comment: @Andremoniy : Could have use `@Controller` too , but will this be a problem?

Comment: It will, because you have to register servlets in web.xml file, but it doesn't relate to Spring at all

Comment: @Andremoniy I have added my web.xml file too. Since I have not configured `DispatcherServlet`, and with the help of Annotations on the `Servlet`, should I need to register my file in `web.xml`?

Comment: You simply shouldn't use servlets in Spring. This is silly as Spring provides you significantly more comfortable way of controllers.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Spring security you don't have to use HttpServlet but Spring.

So what you have to do now is create a spring config xml file and use annotations as "@Controller" for mapping your controller class and "@RequestMapping" for your "/hello".

I would comment but i can't yet.